# Is there a Sublime Text 2 equivalent to Dreamweaver's "Find and Replace > Search: Specific Tag" feature?

Tags: search, plugins, find-and-replace, sublime-text-2, dreamweaver

[image: Dreamweaver Find and Replace dialog]

Is there a function within Sublime Text 2 or a plugin similar to this (besides regex)?

In this example, I wanted set the attribute `border` to `0` for every `img` tag in the document.

Or, say, I wanted to find every `img` tag without an `alt` attribute, and set its `class` to `background`.